# Installation of Neomodel raised error

Tags: python, django, neo4j, installation, pip

I'm trying to install the library Neomodel to use Neo4j in my Django application but it raised many errors:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 208, in copytree
    raise Error, errors
Error: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pytz/__init__.py', '/tmp/pip-rVZOK9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pytz/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-rVZOK9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pytz/__init__.py'")
```

There errors message is a lot of longer but I reduced it to be more concise. Also all the error are the same (Permission Denied). I try to install it using the command:

```
sudo pip install neomodel
```

I have never seen such an error and really don't know what to do to fix. Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using `sudo` with `pip`.

You can run `pip install neomodel --user` to run without a virtualenv but it's generally a good practice to use a [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) instead.